# interractionModel not updating on updateOption() method

Tags: dygraphs

I try to update my interractionModel depending on a variable 'editMode' (which is a boolean)

I use 2 interractionModel : nonInteractiveModel_ and defaultModel. My goal is to disable all interaction when I'm editing my dashboard.

```js
graph.value.updateOptions({
    interactionModel: newProps.editMode ? DygraphInteraction.nonInteractiveModel_ : DygraphInteraction.defaultModel
})
```

These 2 interractionModel  works when I initialize the Dygraph object but not when I update it.

Is there a way do do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by creating a custom interractionModel at the initialization of my Dygraph object :

```js
interactionModel: {
  'willDestroyContextMyself': true,
  'mousedown': function (event, g, context) {
    if (props.editMode) return;
    if (event.button && event.button === 2) return
    context.initializeMouseDown(event, g, context)

    if (event.altKey || event.shiftKey) DygraphInteraction.startPan(event, g, context)
    else DygraphInteraction.startZoom(event, g, context)

    const mousemove = function (event) {
      if (context.isZooming) {
        const d = distanceFromChart(event, g)
        if (d < 100) DygraphInteraction.moveZoom(event, g, context)
        else if (context.dragEndX !== null) {
          context.dragEndX = null
          context.dragEndY = null
          g.clearZoomRect_()
        }
      } else if (context.isPanning) DygraphInteraction.movePan(event, g, context)
    }
    const mouseup = function (event) {
      if (context.isZooming) {
        if (context.dragEndX !== null) DygraphInteraction.endZoom(event, g, context)
        else DygraphInteraction.maybeTreatMouseOpAsClick(event, g, context)
      } else if (context.isPanning) DygraphInteraction.endPan(event, g, context)

      utils.removeEvent(document, 'mousemove', mousemove)
      utils.removeEvent(document, 'mouseup', mouseup);
      context.destroy()
    }

    g.addAndTrackEvent(document, 'mousemove', mousemove)
    g.addAndTrackEvent(document, 'mouseup', mouseup)
  },
  'touchstart': function (event, g, context) {
    if (props.editMode) return;
    startTouch(event, g, context)
  },
  'touchmove': function (event, g, context) {
    if (props.editMode) return;
    moveTouch(event, g, context)
  },
  'touchend': function (event, g, context) {
    if (props.editMode) return;
    endTouch(event, g, context)
  },
  'dblclick': function (event, g, context) {
    if (props.editMode) return;
    if (context.cancelNextDblclick) {
      context.cancelNextDblclick = false
      return
    }

    const e = {
      canvasx: context.dragEndX,
      canvasy: context.dragEndY,
      cancelable: true,
    }

    if (g.cascadeEvents_('dblclick', e)) return
    if (event.altKey || event.shiftKey) return

    g.resetZoom()
  }
}
```

this is a copy of the `defaultModel` of Dygraph but with `if (props.editMode) return` at the beginning of each function.
I also needed to recreate some function on DygraphInterraction class in a external TypeScript file :

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
import * as utils from 'dygraphs/src/dygraph-utils'
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
import Dygraph from 'dygraphs/src/dygraph'

interface DygraphEvent {
    preventDefault(): void,
    touches: Array<Record<string, number>>,
    pageX: unknown,
    pageY: unknown,
    changedTouches: Array<Record<string, number>>
}

interface DygraphContext {
    startTimeForDoubleTapMs: number | null,
    initialTouches: Array<Record<string, number>>
    initialPinchCenter: Record<string, number>,
    touchDirections: Record<string, boolean>,
    initialRange: Record<string, Array<number>>
    doubleTapX: number,
    doubleTapY: number
}

const distanceFromInterval = (x: number, left: number, right: number): number => {
    if (x < left) return left - x
    else if (x > right) return x - right
    else return 0
}

export const distanceFromChart = (event: unknown, g: Dygraph): number => {
    const chartPos = utils.findPos(g.canvas_)
    const box = {
        left: chartPos.x,
        right: chartPos.x + g.canvas_.offsetWidth,
        top: chartPos.y,
        bottom: chartPos.y + g.canvas_.offsetHeight
    }

    const pt = {
        x: utils.pageX(event),
        y: utils.pageY(event)
    }

    const dx = distanceFromInterval(pt.x, box.left, box.right)
    const dy = distanceFromInterval(pt.y, box.top, box.bottom)

    return Math.max(dx, dy)
};

export const startTouch = (event: DygraphEvent, g: Dygraph, context: DygraphContext): void => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (event.touches.length > 1) context.startTimeForDoubleTapMs = null;

    const touches = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < event.touches.length; ++i) {
        const t = event.touches[i]
        touches.push({
            pageX: t.pageX,
            pageY: t.pageY,
            dataX: g.toDataXCoord(t.pageX),
            dataY: g.toDataYCoord(t.pageY)
        })
    }
    context.initialTouches = touches

    if (touches.length === 1) {
        context.initialPinchCenter = touches[0]
        context.touchDirections = { x: true, y: true }
    }
    else if (touches.length >= 2) {
        context.initialPinchCenter = {
            pageX: 0.5 * (touches[0].pageX + touches[1].pageX),
            pageY: 0.5 * (touches[0].pageY + touches[1].pageY),
            dataX: 0.5 * (touches[0].dataX + touches[1].dataX),
            dataY: 0.5 * (touches[0].dataY + touches[1].dataY)
        }

        let initialAngle = 180 / Math.PI * Math.atan2(
            context.initialPinchCenter.pageY - touches[0].pageY,
            touches[0].pageX - context.initialPinchCenter.pageX)

        initialAngle = Math.abs(initialAngle)
        if (initialAngle > 90) initialAngle = 90 - initialAngle

        context.touchDirections = {
            x: (initialAngle < (90 - 45/2)),
            y: (initialAngle > 45/2)
        }
    }

    context.initialRange = {
        x: g.xAxisRange(),
        y: g.yAxisRange()
    }
}

export const moveTouch = (event: DygraphEvent, g: Dygraph, context: DygraphContext): void => {
    context.startTimeForDoubleTapMs = null
    const touches = []

    for (let i = 0; i < event.touches.length; ++i) {
        const t = event.touches[i]
        touches.push({
            pageX: t.pageX,
            pageY: t.pageY
        })
    }
    const initialTouches = context.initialTouches

    let c_now
    const c_init = context.initialPinchCenter;
    if (touches.length === 1) c_now = touches[0]
    else {
        c_now = {
            pageX: 0.5 * (touches[0].pageX + touches[1].pageX),
            pageY: 0.5 * (touches[0].pageY + touches[1].pageY)
        }
    }

    const swipe: Record<string, number> = {
        pageX: c_now.pageX - c_init.pageX,
        pageY: c_now.pageY - c_init.pageY
    }
    const dataWidth = context.initialRange.x[1] - context.initialRange.x[0]
    const dataHeight = context.initialRange.y[0] - context.initialRange.y[1]
    swipe.dataX = (swipe.pageX / g.plotter_.area.w) * dataWidth
    swipe.dataY = (swipe.pageY / g.plotter_.area.h) * dataHeight

    let xScale = 0, yScale = 0;
    if (touches.length === 1) {
        xScale = 1.0
        yScale = 1.0
    }
    else if (touches.length >= 2) {
        const initHalfWidth = (initialTouches[1].pageX - c_init.pageX)
        xScale = (touches[1].pageX - c_now.pageX) / initHalfWidth
        const initHalfHeight = (initialTouches[1].pageY - c_init.pageY)
        yScale = (touches[1].pageY - c_now.pageY) / initHalfHeight
    }

    xScale = Math.min(8, Math.max(0.125, xScale))
    yScale = Math.min(8, Math.max(0.125, yScale))

    let didZoom = false;
    if (context.touchDirections.x) {
        g.dateWindow_ = [
            c_init.dataX - swipe.dataX + (context.initialRange.x[0] - c_init.dataX) / xScale,
            c_init.dataX - swipe.dataX + (context.initialRange.x[1] - c_init.dataX) / xScale
        ]
        didZoom = true
    }

    if (context.touchDirections.y) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
            const axis = g.axes_[i]
            axis.valueRange = [
                c_init.dataY - swipe.dataY + (context.initialRange.y[0] - c_init.dataY) / yScale,
                c_init.dataY - swipe.dataY + (context.initialRange.y[1] - c_init.dataY) / yScale
            ]
            didZoom = true
        }
    }
    g.drawGraph_(false)

    if (didZoom && touches.length > 1 && g.getFunctionOption('zoomCallback')) {
        const viewWindow = g.xAxisRange()
        g.getFunctionOption("zoomCallback").call(g, viewWindow[0], viewWindow[1], g.yAxisRanges())
    }
}

export const endTouch = (event: DygraphEvent, g: Dygraph, context: DygraphContext): void => {
    if (event.touches.length !== 0) startTouch(event, g, context)
    else if (event.changedTouches.length === 1) {
        const now = new Date().getTime()
        const t = event.changedTouches[0]
        if (context.startTimeForDoubleTapMs &&
            now - context.startTimeForDoubleTapMs < 500 &&
            context.doubleTapX && Math.abs(context.doubleTapX - t.screenX) < 50 &&
            context.doubleTapY && Math.abs(context.doubleTapY - t.screenY) < 50) {
            g.resetZoom()
        }
        else {
            context.startTimeForDoubleTapMs = now
            context.doubleTapX = t.screenX
            context.doubleTapY = t.screenY
        }
    }
}
```

and just import them in my first file.